# Buscador en android

Tags: android, buscador

estoy tratando de hacer un buscador en mi app android. Seria algo como esto. Obtengo los datos en un json:

```
{
  "naturaleza": [
    {
      "especie": "flores",
      "array_tipo": [
        {
          "tipo": "rosa",
          "texto": "Las rosas son flores muy lindad. Representan el amor y la amistad para muchas personas."
        },
        {
          "tipo": "tulipan",
          "texto": "Los tulipanes son muy gustados por las personas. Los amantes los utilizan para seducir"
        },
        {
          "tipo": "margarita",
          "texto": "Laa margaritas son flores que huelen muy bien. Son pequeñas y adorman muchos jardines."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "especie": "animales",
      "array_tipo": [
        {
          "tipo": "leon",
          "texto": "El leon es le rey de la selva, es un animal muy fuerte y grane. Todos los demas animales le tiene miedo."
        },
        {
          "tipo": "tiburon",
          "texto": "El tiburon es el rey del mar. Nada muy rapido y es muy furte."
        },
        {
          "tipo": "perro",
          "texto": "El perro es el mejor amigo del hombre. Es parte de la familia, los niños los quieren mucho"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

como ve tengo un array naturaleza que tiene dos elementos (flores y animales) que tb son array y a la ves cada uno tiene tres elementos mas...

Ahora, yo quiero que al buscar la palabra **"rey"** me debuelva la posicion donde se encuntra en el json, o sea (posicion  1 en array naturaleza, posicion 0 en array animales).
Seria algo como, cundo se escriba un apalabra en la barra de busqueda en un listview me muestra los posibles resultados:

el leon es le **rey** de la selva, es un animal (1,0)

el tiburon es el **rey** del mar. Nada muy (1,1)

y cuando seleccione uno este tenga guardada sus posiciones para poder ubicarlos en el json.....
Si alguien puede ayudarme...gracias de antemano...

Comment: esta lista en un `ListView` ? podrias agregar tu codigo, como pretendes hacer el buscador, etc.

Comment: no lo he hecho, tengo la idea, y espero que alguien ayude, lo que no se hacer en si es obtener las posiciones del json

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo un ejemplo que no es lo mas ideal por eficiencia si tendrías un json muy extenso, pero podría orientarte un poco.

```
void buscarJson(String textoBuscar, String tuJson) {
    JSONObject array = null;
    try {
        array = new JSONObject(tuJson);
        JSONArray actual = array.getJSONArray("naturaleza");
        for (int i = 0; i < actual.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray sub = ((JSONObject)actual.get(i)).getJSONArray("array_tipo");
            for (int b = 0; b < sub.length(); b++) {
                if(((JSONObject)sub.get(b)).getString("texto").contains(textoBuscar))
                {
                    Log.e("json", "encontrado en: naturaleza " + i + " posicion " + b);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Simplemente obtiene el array de **naturaleza**, y lo parsea tantas veces como elementos contiene, cada recorrido a su vez parsea el elemento **array_tipo**. Por ultimo comprueba si **texto** contiene el string que se le pase y en caso de que si, tienes almacenado en la variable **i** la posición del array **naturaleza** y en **b** la posición dentro de **array_tipo**

Comment: eso pudiera serbir, pero los json con los que trabajo son genericos, no simpre tienen los mismos niveles, por ejemplo en este caso solo hay un array con dos array mas dentro...pero pudiese darse el caso de que el json tenga un array, con dos array mas dentro, y uno de esos array con otro array y asi sucesivamente, por eso tengo que recorrer de dentro hacia fuera

Comment: ¿ Pero el texto a buscar siempre esta dentro de **texto** ? O sea, solo cambia la estructura agregando por ejemplo un nuevo array, ¿digamos algo así como una categoría extra? **naturaleza>flores>blancas>"resultados"**

Comment: si mas menos, pero entonces como voy a controlar la cantidad de ciclos que tengo que implementar?

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción que tienes es crear tu objeto que podemos llamar Ser, el cual tendrá dentro un String especie y un Array de tipo. Este array tendrá dentro 2 String, no se si me he explicado muy bien la verdad...

Si haces esto, al deserializarlo con la clase Gson te traduce directamente el json a objetos, donde es mucho más fácil recorrerlos, acceder a sus propiedades y guardar sus posiciones.